# MongoDB change stream over HTTP or WebSocket

Tags: mongodb, websocket, notifications, monitoring

I would like to be notified about changes in my MongoDB database within a web application. Is it possible to consume [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) via HTTP or WebSockets?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Im confused too about change streams vs websockets. As i understand change streams are a implementation of websockets by mongodb, am i wrong?

Comment: No, I didn't. I gave a try to google firebase.